# Why does tmux mess up my Ubuntu login, though it works ok once logged in for new windows?

Tags: login, tmux, bashrc

Why, after a Ubuntu 14.04 software update, does have `exec tmux` in my .bashrc lead to not being able to log in (though previously it worked fine for years) and how to fix ?

Investigation:

I recently did a Ubuntu 14.04 update and then couldn't even log in to the system at all.  Only the fact that I once created another account on this machine (**so do that now yourself! have the account have little to no .bashrc stuff**) made fixing it relatively easy.  Having previously made an extra account that has admin saved me.  Also the fact that I can log into that account and then when doing

```
su other_account_name
```

- Which initially still fails as it tries to use .bashrc -

I can actually do

```
su other_account_name -s /bin/sh
```

instead to just use the basic sh shell and avoid bash.
*Then* I can edit the bashrc and fix what's wrong, save the file and all is restored.  Phew!

*Investigation complete.  Back to the question...*

So, after all this, I finally tracked down the issue to the fact that having `exec tmux` in my .bashrc using

```
[ -z "$TMUX" ] && command -v tmux > /dev/null && TERM=xterm-256color && tmux
```

was messing up logging in initially.

However, if I'm already logged in, that allows new windows (that have tmux activated) to be created without a problem.

How to fix and be able to use tmux and have my .bashrc still work for initial login?

Notes:

- I *can* do `exec tmux` after logging in and it gets activated and I can use it ok.
- I tried changing `exec tmux` to `tmux` in the line in `.bashrc` and it 'half' helped - I get an 'invalid' message popup* when I log in to the account - but tmux has been invoked and is usable.
- I checked and I seem to have a current version - 1.9a - of tmux
- The popup that I get when I changed my `./bashrc` to have `tmux` instead of `exec tmux` contains:

  Error foud when loading /home/durrant/.profile:\n\n
  open terminal failure: not a terminal\n\n
  As a result the session will not be configured correctly.
  You should fix the problem as soon as possible.
- I've also tried having

  tmux

on its own line in my `.bashrc` file and also having

```
[ -z "$TMUX" ] && tmux
```

but got the same errors

Comment: There are so many issues with this approach: first, `.bashrc` is read *every* time you open a shell, second, the TERM variable inside tmux *has* to be set to screen*, and third, your overall approach is just wrong: spawn a tmux session on login and then open shells in that, not the other way around...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, as I have not found an actual fix, my temporary workaround is to not invoke tmux in my .bashrc.

I've created an alias `t` for tmux so that once I open a terminal window I can just type `t[return]` to enable tmux for that session.